# xcode project warning "unable to read symbols" after renaming the project

Tags: objective-c

I started my xcode project in a silly name - "SimpleScrollView"

Now the project is ending, I renamed my xcode project - "PondsFacialFoam"

I also renamed my Main AppDelegate and the Main view controller's name.
SimpleScrollViewAppDelegate -> PondsFacialFoamAppDelegate
SimpleScrollViewViewController -> PondsFacialFoamViewController

Basically, wherever the "SimpleScrollView" exists, i replaced it with "PondsFacialFoam"

BUT

When everything is renamed, and it can be built and run successfully, i started to receive a strange warning:

```
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/terrencetee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PondsFacialFoam-ddlflpcanuidbyfgsurtrnbegtmj/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SimpleScrollView.app/PondsFacialFoam (file not found).
```

It appears that somewhere, the project is still refering to a non existence "SimpleScrollView.app...."

Where is this ?

Comment: Did you use xcode's project -> rename feature?

Comment: It's being referenced in project.pbxproj. Did you rename the executable as well?

Comment: hi zaky, i m using xcode 4 tat rename button doesnt exist anymore...
hi vakio, yes i can see "SimpleScrollView" still in the pbxproj, wat do u mean by "rename the executable"?

Comment: Did you do a clean + rebuild?

Comment: hi kobski, i tried many times still the same :(

Comment: `grep -nr SimpleScrollView *` over your project directory.