# Xcode warning of "Unable to read symbols" points to non-existent path under DerivedData

Tags: xcode, warnings

A new Xcode 4.2 project of mine is giving the following warning *only* when running on the device (as in, not with the Simulator):

warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-caubqehwsicqvmfcjxvvwaprgulm/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SomeOtherString.app/MyApp (file not found).
warning: No copy of SomeOtherString.app/MyApp found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.

I do not know where this "SomeOtherString.app" is coming from, but I would like to tell Xcode to stop looking for it.  Trouble is, I cannot find where it is being set.  I have looked in all the project settings, opened project.pbxproj and looked in there -- nothing.

I finally did a recursive grep for "SomeOtherString" inside my project folder -- the string was not found!

And yes, I have done many "cleans" and have cleared out my DerivedData directory.  But Xcode insists that MyApp belongs under "SomeOtherString.app"!

So, my question is: where on earth is this path being stored?

The closest other SO issue I could find was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5815920/xcode-project-warning-unable-to-read-symbols-after-renaming-the-project), but no one ever posted a solution.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Is there any chance that you're using OpenEars?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found out what was going on here.  Even though SomeOtherString was in fact nowhere in my project, I had apparently chosen a bundle ID that was identical to another app whose name was SomeOtherString that Xcode knew about.

I guess this could be an issue if one clones a project -- make sure you use a bundle ID that you have not already used before.